# I can't understand why it comes this

Tags: ios, swift

[image: why did it come this!!]

I set 4 constraints(top,bottom,left,right) to the superview(content view) for the scroll view.

And I set 2 constraints(bottom,right) to the superview(content view) for the page control.

But the result showed on the picture.

the scroll view didn't fill full of the content view but the page control perfectly did it.

I can't understand why it came this.

I hope that someone can help me T.T

[image: the new picture]

This problem hasn't solved and I think the problem maybe the code?

So, I print the code here.Somebody can find the root cause here?

[image: yellow warning here]

Somebody mention the yellow warning and I post the capture here.

Comment: Click on yellow warning and update constraint and check whether it's proper or not

Comment: Please use a more meaningful title - the one you're using would fit with pretty much any question on SO, giving no idea what the problem is about

Comment: @Antonio Sorry I'll do it next time.

Comment: What does the yellow warning say? Have you tried updating the frame?

Comment: What the yellow warning said is not the cause of this problem.That is irrelevant to layout.

Comment: The yellow warning is indeed autolayout-related warning (since you can see that there's a dashed line around the scrollview - there's something wrong that Xcode is trying to tell you).

Answer (score 0):

Because the UIScrollView also needs `width` and `height` constraints.

Setting `equal width` and `equal height` constraints to the superview should fix the issue.

Comment: No it doesn't. It needs just to pin it. Content size is the key.

Comment: No,I set the four bounds constraints of the content view and it should be fill with full the view just but not.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire screen layout is organised by AutoLayout you can't set the frame property of UIView, which is in the view hierarchy. Unless you specify the view doesn't listen to AutoLayout by disabling this in the .nib of .storyboard for the entire file or by specifying this in for the particular view by setting a property.